# Facebook does not read my meta title tag in sharer.php

Tags: facebook

I am trying to share a link using sharer.php on facebook.I have used the code

```
<a style="cursor: pointer;" target="_blank" title="
<?php echo ucfirst($this->headline); ?>" 
href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php echo $url ?>" >
```

`$url` is urlencoded here.

i have used the og meta tags as follows:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Test" />
<meta property="og:type" content="company" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://75.125.190.162:7113/index.php?option=com_realtyna&amp;view=propertyshow&amp;building_name=&amp;category=FLAT&amp;country=&amp;state=Ariana&amp;city=Ariana+Ville&amp;zone=&amp;listing_type=&amp;bedroom=Three+bedrooms&amp;pid=180&amp;Itemid=3&amp;lang=en" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://75.125.190.162:7113/components/com_realtyna/uploads/180/180_main_iHq29q.jpg" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Test" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="100000626812232" />
```

The problem is that on sharing it on facebook it doesnt shows the title which i specified here.It seems to pick the title of the page but changing it also doesnt helps.I cant figure out from where it is picking up the title.
Help Anyone.
Url to the page is :

> http://75.125.190.162:7113/index.php?option=com_realtyna&view=propertyshow&building_name=&category=FLAT&country=&state=Ariana&city=Ariana+Ville&zone=&listing_type=&bedroom=Three+bedrooms&pid=180&Itemid=3&lang=en

Comment: I am using this

http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s= 100&amp;p[title]=<?php echo ucfirst($this->headline); ?>&amp;p[url]=<?php echo $url ?>&amp;p[images][0]=<?php echo $facebookImage; ?>

 for now.But it shows only one image.I dont know how to send multiple images using this method so that user can select a thumbnail to post.i have tried it like this  
p[images][1]= image2 but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Just put multiple og:image tags and it will give the user an option to choose which photo they want to use.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://75.125.190.162:7113/components/com_realtyna/uploads/180/180_main_iHq29q.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://75.125.190.162:7113/components/com_realtyna/uploads/180/180_main_47Lcge.jpg" />
```

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/